# Twilio Video stucks in react native ios

Tags: react-native, twilio

Twilio video chat stuck on react native ios when other user goes to background and returns back to the app. I'm using https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc.

Comment: I would recommend you ask within [the issues of react-native-twilio-video-webrtc](https://github.com/blackuy/react-native-twilio-video-webrtc/issues) as no-one here seems to have answered and (as a Twilio employee) I don't know the answer and haven't used this community provided plugin.

Comment: @philnash Ok thanks.